# Posting to a Neo4j server using node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, neo4j

Disclaimer: This is related to another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326787/neo4j-in-azure-mobile-services). I was advised to ask a new question rather than to update that one, I hope that this is correct. If not please let me know and ignor this question.

I have been trying to use a Neo4j in Microsoft Azure, using [this tutorial](http://www.buzzfrog.se/index.php/2013/12/use-neo4j-as-your-database-in-azure-mobile-services/). I created a VM running Linux and neo4j. I know his works fine because I have been able to access the database via the web admin portal, where I can create and delete entries. However the problem comes when I try to use node.js to insert elements.

Here is the code for the script:

```
    function insert(item, user, request) {
    //comment to trigger .js creation
    var neo4j = require('neo4j');
    var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://<username>:<password>@neo4jmobile.cloudapp.net:7474');
    var node = db.createNode({ name: item.name });
    node.save(function (err, node) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error saving new node to database:', err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Node saved to database with id:', node.id);
        }
    });

    request.execute();

}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Error saving new node to database: { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  stack: [Getter/Setter],
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  __frame:
   { name: 'GraphDatabase_prototype__getRoot__1',
     line: 76,
     file: '\\\\10.211.156.195\\volume-0-default\\bf02c8bd8f7589d46ba1\\4906fa4587734dd087df8e641513f602\\site\\wwwroot\\App_Data\\config\\scripts\\node_modules\\neo4j\\lib\\GraphDatabase.js',
     prev:
      { name: 'GraphDatabase_prototype_getServices__2',
        line: 99,
        file: '\\\\10.211.156.195\\volume-0-default\\bf02c8bd8f7589d46ba1\\4906fa4587734dd087df8e641513f602\\site\\wwwroot\\App_Data\\config\\scripts\\node_modules\\neo4j\\lib\\GraphDatabase.js',
        prev: [Object],
        active: false,
        offset: 5,
        col: 12 },
     active: false,
     offset: 5,
     col: 12 },
  rawStack: [Getter] }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you access the Neo4j browser of the target Linux server? This looks like a firewall issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is still wrong: `http://<username>:<password>@http://neo4jmobile.cloudapp.net:7474` should be `http://<username>:<password>@neo4jmobile.cloudapp.net:7474`

In the referenced tutorial (which is quite good btw) he says:

```
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://<username>:<password>@<your neo url>.cloudapp.net:7474');
```

Where  refers to the hostname, i.e.: `neo4jmobile`

Comment: I actually had changed that, as I said in the previous post. I accidentally didn't correct it in this post. But I have fixed that and it is not the problem. Thanks for taking the time to respond though and I am sorry that I messed up like that.